# Android Multiple image upload not send data to server

Tags: java, android, image, upload, multipart

Hello I am working with android . I want to send a multipart data to asp.net server which contains a text and mulltiple images. I can able to send only one image to send to server. I used this code

```
for(int i=0;i<Captured_imagePath.size();i++)
                {

                    File file2 = new File("my folder path" + Captured_imagePath.get(i));


                    entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(file2.getName(), file2, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), Captured_imagePath.get(i));

                    entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);


                }
```

where Captured_imagePath is array list of image names in the folder.I tried to print the sending data to a file and it works fine in the case when I send only one image, if I used more than one image, means if Captured_imagePath has size >1 it will not print the sending data and image not send to server.Is there any problem with my code ? I stucked with this problem. Please help me Thanks in advance :)

Comment: this one is the simplest and clean way ,refer this , http://mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upload-multiple-images-on-php.html and let me know if you are facing still any issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
   `   
for ( int i= 0; i < size ; i++ ){

    try {
    File file = new File("my folder path" + Captured_imagePath.get(i));

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); //to send in multiparts
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity) ;
    httpClient.execute(httppost); // can catch httpResponse here
    } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStacktrace() ; }
    }`
```

where file is File var.

Comment: this will send http request as array size times. right ?

Comment: yes,  provided you build your httpClient correctly.